# Collective word for prefix, stem and suffix

Tags: single-word-requests

Please, is there a collective word for all the parts of a word, prefix, stem and suffix?

Comment: Are you looking for the word *affix*?

Comment: The prefix, stem, and suffixes of any English word together yields… the ***word***. Or was that not what you meant?

Comment: A *morpheme* is the smallest meaningful unit of a word, whether it be affix or base.

Answer (score 2):

***Word part*** would be the only phrase that can be considered as a *hypernym* for all parts of a word. (Some sources mention as ***word element*** also).

[A few sources: [1](http://www.sparknotes.com/testprep/books/newsat/powertactics/vocab/chapter2section4.rhtml), [2](http://www.massasoit.mass.edu/acad_depts/humanities_finearts/english/resource_room/WordParts.pdf), [3](http://www.infoplease.com/cig/grammar-style/attaching-prefixes-suffixes-bits-pieces.html), [4](http://www.eslgold.com/vocabulary/word_parts.html)]

If you didn't say *stem* but said *root*, ***morpheme*** would be the collective word. Because roots are composed of only one morpheme while stems can be composed of more than one morpheme. So we can't say that all stems are morphemes.

But some sources still mention stem as a morpheme because they can be roots or inflectional roots.

In general, morphemes are affixes, roots and clitics.